# Jest moduleNameMapper to find files: "resolver": undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, package.json

I have a text file (amongst others) in the `component` folder under the path: `src/components/text`

However, Jest does not find this file when the webpack alias `import Text from "components/text";` is used.

I tried adding to `package.json`:

```js
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass|svg)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",
      "^assets/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/assets/$1",
      "^utils/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/utils/$1",
      "^styles/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/styles/$1"
      "/^locales\/(.*)$/": "<rootDir>/src/locales/$1",
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./dist"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!(@opt-ui|@equinor))"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/tests/coverage/"
  }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```js
Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module components/text mapped as:
    /Users/olahalvorsen/cssu-dashboard-client/src/components$1.
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^components\/(.*)$/": "/Users/olahalvorsen/cssu-dashboard-client/src/components$1"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

So, `"^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1"`in the moduleNameMapper solved the first issue above:)

But now I'm getting another error:

```
FAIL  src/pages/errorpage/tests/error.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'locales' from 'src/utils/helpers/helpers.js'

    Require stack:
      src/utils/helpers/helpers.js
      src/components/text/index.jsx
      src/pages/errorpage/error.jsx
      src/pages/errorpage/tests/error.test.jsx

      29 | import { nb, enGB } from "date-fns/locale";
      30 | 
    > 31 | import translations from "locales";
         | ^
      32 | 
      33 | export const capitalize = string => {
      34 |   if (typeof string === "string") {
```

I updated the package.json above. The relative directory of locales is `src/locales`. Shouldn't this work:

```
  "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^locales/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales$1",
```

I tried using:       `"/^locales\/(.*)$/": "<rootDir>/src/locales/$1"`

### EDIT, found solution:

The solution was to use: `"^locales(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales/$1"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the log I guess your configuration is `/^components\/(.*)$/: "<rootDir>/src/components$1"` which is different from your given code is `^components(.*)$`.

Assuming the above is the right one, so you might need to change to as following to make it work properly:

```json
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^components\/(.*)$/": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1" // You missed out `/` before the rest value `$1`
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now have another module not being found. Do you have any tips here? I tried the way you described above for this one as well with no luck.

Comment: I got it to work now! With `"^locales(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales/$1".`

Comment: You should exclude `/` from the rest which is much better like this: `^locales\/(.*)$`

Comment: It seems you have had another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821409/reactjs-npm-test-jest-encountered-an-unexpected-token. Did you check the answer I dropped for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks- it worked. I have yet another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854258/typeerror-styled-symbol-is-not-a-function-reactjs-and-jest :)

Answer (score -1):

**Check the path to your fileMock.js**

In my case, I took a long time to realize that the `___test___` folder had three underscores instead of two.

And check the content of the file
In my case, this is: `module.exports = 'test-file-stub'`

You will also need to [install jest-transform-stub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub) first.