# Reactjs npm test: Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm getting an error when running npm test. I feel like I have tried every existing suggestion online, but I can not get it to work.

Here is my **package.json**. I thought the    `"transformIgnorePatterns": [ "/node_modules/(?!@total/*)", ],` would solve the issue, but it didn't.

```
{
  "name": "ssu-dashboard-client",
  "version": "2.1.0",
  "description": "Dashboard for operation planning",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "olahalvorsen",
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --watch webpack.config.js --watch server.js",
    "dev:inspect": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --inspect server.js ",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.12.1",
    "@opt-ui/accordion": "^1.0.13",
    "@opt-ui/alert": "^1.0.1",
    "@opt-ui/button": "^1.0.6",
    "@opt-ui/card": "^1.0.3",
    "@opt-ui/checkbox": "^1.1.2",
    "@opt-ui/datepicker": "^1.0.3",
    "@opt-ui/dropdown": "^1.0.12",
    "@opt-ui/icon": "^1.0.2",
    "@opt-ui/input": "^1.0.17",
    "@opt-ui/menu": "^1.0.2",
    "@opt-ui/message": "^1.0.1",
    "@opt-ui/modal": "^1.0.11",
    "@opt-ui/notification": "^1.0.29",
    "@opt-ui/pagination": "^1.0.13",
    "@opt-ui/popover": "^1.0.28",
    "@opt-ui/radio": "^1.0.0",
    "@opt-ui/select": "^1.0.12",
    "@opt-ui/slider": "^1.0.2",
    "@opt-ui/styles": "^1.0.4",
    "@opt-ui/switch": "^1.0.2",
    "@opt-ui/tabs": "^1.0.25",
    "@opt-ui/topbar": "^1.0.1",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.20",
    "axios": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-preset-jest": "^26.6.2",
    "color": "^3.1.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.4.0",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.12.0",
    "date-fns-tz": "^1.0.10",
    "highcharts": "7.1.2",
    "highcharts-drilldown": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-more": "^0.1.7",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^2.2.2",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-google-charts": "^2.0.29",
    "react-highcharts": "^16.0.2",
    "react-is": "^16.13.1",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.11.2",
    "react-measure": "^2.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.1",
    "react-saga": "^0.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.27.4",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "tinymce": "^5.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^4.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.2",
    "adal-node": "^0.1.28",
    "applicationinsights": "^1.3.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.11.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-logger": "0.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-styled-components-config": "^0.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.7",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.4",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "worker-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "verbose": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass|svg)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/components/$1",
      "^assets/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/assets/$1",
      "^utils/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/utils/$1",
      "^locales/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/locales$1",

      "^styles/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/styles/$1"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./dist"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!@total/*)"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/tests/coverage/"
  }
}
```

Babel config:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        test: {
            presets: [
                [
                    "@babel/preset-env",
                    {
                        modules: "commonjs",
                        debug: false
                    }
                ],
                "@babel/preset-flow",
                "@babel/preset-react"
            ],
            plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
            ]
        },
        production: {
            presets: [
                ["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }],
                "@babel/preset-flow",
                "@babel/preset-react"
            ],
            plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
            ]
        },
        development: {
            presets: [
                ["@babel/preset-env", { modules: false }],
                "@babel/preset-flow",
                "@babel/preset-react"
            ],
            plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

**Error:**

```
 FAIL  src/pages/errorpage/tests/error.test.jsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/my-computer/repo-name/node_modules/@opt-ui/icons/node_modules/@total/eds-icons/dist/icons.esm.js:5598
    export { accessible, accessible_forward, account_circle, add, add_box, add_circle_filled, add_circle_outlined, alarm, alarm_add, alarm_off, alarm_on, all_out, android, apple_airplay, apple_app_store, apple_logo, apps, archive, arrow_back, arrow_back_ios, arrow_down, arrow_drop_down, arrow_drop_left, arrow_drop_right, arrow_drop_up, arrow_forward, arrow_forward_ios, arrow_up, assignment, assignment_important, assignment_return, assignment_returned, assignment_turned_in, assignment_user, attach_file, attachment, autorenew, baby, bandage, bar_chart, battery, battery_alert, battery_charging, battery_unknown, beach, bearing, beat, bike, block, blocked, blocked_off, bluetooth, bluetooth_connected, bluetooth_disabled, bluetooth_searching, boat, bookmark_collection, bookmark_filled, bookmark_outlined, bookmarks, border_all, border_bottom, border_clear, border_color, border_horizontal, border_inner, border_left, border_outer, border_right, border_style, border_top, border_verticle, breifcase, brush, bubble_chart, build_wrench, bus, business, cable, cafe, cake, calendar, calendar_accept, calendar_date_range, calendar_event, calendar_reject, calendar_today, call, call_add, call_end, camera, camera_add_photo, car, car_wash, category, change_history, check, check_circle_outlined, checkbox, checkbox_indeterminate, checkbox_outline, chevron_down, chevron_left, chevron_right, chevron_up, chrome, cinema, circuit, city, clear, close, close_cricle_outlined, closed_caption_filled, closed_caption_outlined, cloud, cloud_done, cloud_download, cloud_off, cloud_upload, cocktail, code, coffee, collection_1, collection_2, collection_3, collection_4, collection_5, collection_6, collection_7, collection_8, collection_9, collection_9_plus, color_palette, comment, comment_add, comment_chat, comment_chat_off, comment_discussion, comment_important, comment_more, comment_notes, comment_solid, communte, compare, compass_calibration, computer, contact_email, contact_phone, contacts, convenience_store, copy, credit_card, crop, crop_rotate, cut, dashboard, delete_forever, delete_multiple, delete_to_trash, departure_board, desktop_mac, desktop_windwos, details, device_unknown, dialpad, dice, dining, directions, dns, do_not_disturb, dock, dollar, done, done_all, donut_large, donut_outlined, download, download_done, drag_handle, drink, dropper, edit, edit_text, eject, email, email_alpha, email_draft, error_filled, error_outlined, ev_station, exit_to_app, explore, explore_off, external_link, face, facebook, facebook_messenger, fast_food, fast_forward, fast_rewind, favorite_filled, favorite_outlined, file, file_add, file_copy, file_description, filter_alt, filter_list, fingerprint_scanner, first_page, flag, flagged, flagged_off, flame, flare, flash_off, flash_on, flight, flight_land, flight_takeoff, flip, flip_to_back, flip_to_front, flower, focus_center, folder, folder_add, folder_favorite, folder_open, folder_shared, format_align_center, format_align_justify, format_align_left, format_align_right, format_bold, format_clear, format_color_fill, format_color_reset, format_color_text, format_highlight, format_indent_decrease, format_indent_increase, format_italics, format_line_spacing, format_list_bulleted, format_list_numbered, format_quote, format_shape, format_size, format_stikethrough, format_underline, forward_10, forward_30, forward_5, fridge, fullscreen, fullscreen_exit, functions, gamepad, gas, gas_station, gavel, gear, gesture, github, google_cast, google_cast_connected, google_maps, google_play, google_translate, gps_fixed, gps_not_fixed, gps_off, grid_off, grid_on, grocery_store, group, group_add, gym, headseat_mic, headset, hearing, help, help_outline, high_priority, history, home, hospital, hotel, hourglass_empty, hourglass_full, image, image_add, inbox, infinity, info_circle, insert_link, instagram, invert_colors, ios_logo, iphone, key, keyboard, keyboard_backspace, keyboard_capslock, keyboard_hide, keyboard_return, keyboard_space_bar, keyboard_tab, keyboard_voice, label, label_off, language, last_page, launch, laundry, layers, layers_off, library, library_add, library_books, library_image, library_music, library_pdf, library_video, light, lightbulb, link, link_off, linkedin, list, lock, lock_add, lock_off, lock_open, loop, mail_unread, mall, map, maximize, measure, meeting_room, meeting_room_off, memory, menu, mic, mic_off, mic_outlined, microsoft_edge, microsoft_excel, microsoft_onedrive, microsoft_outlook, microsoft_powerpoint, microsoft_word, minimize, missed_video_call, money, mood_extreamly_happy, mood_extreamly_sad, mood_happy, mood_neutral, mood_sad, mood_very_happy, mood_very_sad, more_horizontal, more_verticle, motorcycle, mouse, move_to_inbox, movie, movie_file, multiline_chart, music_note, music_note_off, nature, nature_people, navigation, near_me, new_alert, new_label, notifications, notifications_active, notifications_add, notifications_important, notifications_off, notifications_paused, offline, offline_saved, opacity, open_in_browser, pan_tool, parking, paste, pause, pause_circle, pause_circle_outlined, person, person_add, pharmacy, phone, pie_chart, pin, pin_drop, pizza, place, place_add, place_edit, place_person, place_unknown, placeholder_icon, platform, play, play_circle, play_circle_outlined, playlist_add, playlist_added, playlist_play, pool, power, power_button, power_button_off, pram, pregnant_woman, pressure, print, print_off, priority_high, priority_low, puzzle, puzzle_filled, radio_button_selected, radio_button_unselected, railway, receipt, record, record_voice, record_voice_off, redo, refresh, remove, remove_outlined, reorder, repeat, repeat_one, replay, replay_10, replay_30, replay_5, reply, reply_all, report, report_bug, report_off, res_4k_filled, res_4k_outlined, res_hd_filled, res_hd_outlined, restaurant, restore, restore_from_trash, restore_page, rotate3d, rotate_90_degrees_ccw, rotate_left, rotate_right, router, run, satellite, save, scanner, scatter_plot, school, search, search_find_replace, search_in_page, searched_history, security, select_all, send, setting_backup_restore, settings, share, share_screen, share_screen_off, shipping, shopping_basket, shopping_card, shopping_cart_add, shopping_cart_off, shuffle, sim_card, skip_next, skip_previous, skype, slideshow, smartwatch, smoking, smoking_off, snooze, snow, sort, sort_by_alpha, speaker, speaker_group, spellcheck, spotify, star_circle, star_filled, star_half, star_outlined, stop, store, style, subdirectory_arrow_left, subdirectory_arrow_right, subway, subway_tunnel, sun, support, swap_horizontal, swap_horizontal_circle, swap_verticle, swap_verticle_circle, switch_off, switch_on, sync, sync_off, sync_problem, table_chart, tablet_android, tablet_ipad, tag, taxi, terrain, text_field, text_rotation_angled_down, text_rotation_angled_up, text_rotation_down, text_rotation_none, text_rotation_up, text_rotation_verticle, texture, thermostat, thumbs_down, thumbs_up, thumbs_up_down, ticket, time, timeline, timer, timer_off, title, toc, toilet, toll, touch, track_changes, traffic_light, train, tram, transfer, transit, transit_enter_exit, translate, trending_down, trending_flat, trending_up, trip_origin, tune, turbine, tv, twitter, unarchive, undo, unfold_less, unfold_more, unsubscribe, update, upload, usb, users_circle, van, verified, verified_user, verticle_align_bottom, verticle_align_center, verticle_align_top, verticle_split, video_call, video_chat, videocam, videocam_off, view_360, view_agenda, view_array, view_carousel, view_column, view_day, view_list, view_module, view_quilt, view_stream, view_week, visibility, visibility_off, volume_down, volume_mute, volume_off, volume_up, walk, warning_filled, warning_outlined, waves, whats_app, wheelchair, widgets, wifi, wifi_off, work, work_off, work_outline, world, wrap_text, youtube, youtube_alt, zoom_in, zoom_out };
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@opt-ui/icons/index.js:15:38)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.752 s
Ran all test suites matching /error.test.jsx/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
➜  cssu-dashboard-client git:(feature/set-up-testing) ✗ 
➜  cssu-dashboard-client git:(feature/set-up-testing) ✗ npm test error.test.jsx

> ssu-dashboard-client@2.1.0 test /Users/stian.ismar/cssu-dashboard-client
> jest "error.test.jsx"
```

My test is really simple now, I'm just trying to get Jest up and running:

```
import React from "react";
import error from '../error'
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";



test("renders correct content", () => {
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<error/>)
    screen.debug()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your situation is to be nested twice `node_modules` (`node_modules/@opt-ui/icons/node_modules/@equinor/eds-icons`), so you might have to set both `@opt-ui` and `@equinor` to re-transpile.

However, I have an idea which I'm not 100% the following way would work but it's worth trying though:

```js
{
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!(@opt-ui|@equinor))`],
}
```