# Jest setting up path aliases

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

This is my `jest.config.json`

```json
{
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "ts"],
  "rootDir": ".",
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testRegex": ".e2e-spec.ts$",
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^~/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  },
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
  }
}
```

When i run tests jest throws error:
`
Configuration error:

```
Could not locate module ~/users/user.entity mapped as:
C:\Users\makow\Documents\Projects\rigtch-music-api\test\src\$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^~\/(.*)/": "C:\Users\makow\Documents\Projects\rigtch-music-api\test\src\$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
`
```

How can I setup path aliases for jest

Comment: Not to pass the buck, but is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64816788/jest-modulenamemapper-to-find-files-resolver-undefined) similar enough to point you in the right direction?

Comment: I will check it out

Comment: Might be worth trying testyts https://github.com/Testy/TestyTs